# Merge foundation navigation with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Has anybody found a way of having the foundation "top bar" functionality (child menu items slide to the left on mobile) - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html on the bootstrap framework.

I love the way foundation has this mobile nav slide if it has a child rather than bootstraps way of just stacking the child items.

I did try and merge the two, ideally I wanted to stick to Bootstrap markup and css. I know I can download just the top bar from foundation and stick it at the top of my bootstrap template but that means having excess css and could get confusing for future development.

Has anybody managed to do this or have seen a bootstrap tailored script to mimic this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Well Tom, You can merge foundation with Bootstrap. The only deference between these two frameworks are Zurb Foundation use "em" for everything and Bootstrap uses "Pixels". And i am currently working on the project by merging Top bar for foundation with bootstrap for layout design.

You wont able to get issue regarding layout designs. Even Foundation uses "row" class but the sub class varies in bootstrap like "col-md=2" so on,It wont be a problem for you.

And if you download by clicking only top Bar in customize Foundation option. Foundation.css will be downloaded which will have everything. So keep topbar and related elements in foundation.css and delete other css property so that you wont get confused.

so no worry's about merging two frameworks.Go ahead. Ask questions if you face any further issues.